# Reduce size of SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-size

How can I reduce my SQL Server 2008 database size?

My application is slow as as a result of increasing db volume.

Answer (score 5):

You have three options, none of which will involve me telling you to shrink your database:

1. Archive old data by deleting it
2. Archive old data by moving it to another database and use views to allow people historical access
3. If you're on Enterprise Edition, check out [data compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/data-compression)

There are also magical options which require no data movement or deletion:

4. Add as much RAM as your server and licensing allows
5. Tune indexes using a script like [sp_BlitzIndex](http://firstresponderkit.org) (full disclosure, I'm one of the authors of that script)